# Add lines to file in linux

Tags: linux, scripting

I want to add a line to a file maintaining the exact pattern

Line i want to add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I dont want to add the values of the variables to the file

**What I did:**

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_PATH/bin" | sudo tee -a /home/admin/Vishal/test.sh
```

**My Output:**

Contains numerous paths instead of **export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin**

Comment: You need to escape the dollar signs like this `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_PATH/bin"` or use single quotes like this `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_PATH/bin'`

Comment: You absolutely must not use `sudo` to write to a file which belongs to yourself. If the file already exists, you'll be fine, but if the file is created by `root`, you will never be able to edit it yourself.

Comment: You really don't want to add that line.  You will end up with shells in which PATH has redundant entries (eg  `/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/java/latest/bin:/opt/java/latest/bin:/opt/java/latest/bin`).  Always use some form of pathmunge: do not blindly append without checking if the desired values are already in the path.

Comment: Looking at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576295/delete-a-line-containing-exact-pattern-in-linux) I will repeat my comment there: What you are doing seems like a horrible idea. Make the script update the path dynamically instead. Don't seesaw-edit the script itself.

Comment: @WilliamPursell i have that in mind but have no idea how to check if the path entry already exist in $PATH

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you need single quotes instead of double. But really, you should not be editing your script file. Instead, make it accept a parameter which tells it whether or not to update the `PATH`.

```
case $1 in --update-path) PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin;; esac
```

If you run `/home/admin/Vishal/test.sh --update-path`  it will add the Java directory; without the option, it won't.